# Using tnsnames.ora in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, datamapper, tnsnames

How can I use the database connection information in tnsnames.ora when connecting with Rails?

I tried setting the `database:` or the `host:` fields in the database.yml to the SID, but neither worked.

I verified that sqlplus can connect to the database, so the tnsnames.ora is correct.

I'm using DataMapper on Rails 3 if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we spoke in #datamapper a couple days ago.  Sqlplus is a piece of Oracle software which interfaces with what i presume is their loadbalancing system.

DataMapper assumes that there is a 1 to 1 mapping between a repository and a datastore.  Typically this means that you assume that load balancing is handled datastore side (say mysql or postgres clustering).

However, there is nothing preventing someone from writing a library that would let DataMapper hot swap between a group of repositories, if it were possible to get a readout of the load on each of the datastores associated with each repository (i.e. write your own little load balancing router).

The company i work for uses DataMapper repositories in exactly this fashion (for separability of records, rather than for load balancing).

it's as simple as:

```
DataMapper.repository(seed_repository_symbol) { return your_code_block.call }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of fussing with this myself I discovered the answer to be:

```
# WORKS
development:
  adapter: oracle
  host: devdb
  username: user
  password: pwd
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.1, DM 1.2.0 on Win7 with both 32-bit and 64-bit regular Oracle clients installed.

One very important thing I discovered along the way: **You must restart the rails dev server between each mod of database.yml to pick up the changes.**  I wasted a lot of time not knowing this.  For some reason the DataMapper setup wasn't picking up changes here like is normal with the dev server.

History:

I was told the answer was this (by another developer at another company who uses JRuby on Windows):

```
# DID NOT WORK
development:
  adapter: oracle
  database: user/pwd@devdb
```

That did not work for me and I suspected the answer was to use a colon (based on `DataMapper.setup` syntax):

```
# DID NOT WORK
development:
  adapter: oracle
  database: user:pwd@devdb
```

This did not work either so I tested manual connections in the IRM and studied the response from `DataMapper.setup`.  It puts the SID in `host` and does not indicate `database` so I tried the same in database.yml.  It worked.

Comment: Just found [this blog](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/06/how-to-change-your-rails-database.html) which is also relevant.